# WPF: How to trigger PropertyChanged on INotifyPropertyChanged items in my view model from my control?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Let's say I have my own `ItemSource` in my control. It can assign `ObservableCollection` type to it, so, the collection could be notified if my control changes a property of an item.

The problem is when I get the item modified and I know the collection implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I don't know how to trigger the `PropertyChanged` event. The interface defines only event, not the method that triggers it.

Yet somehow original WPF controls do that. I feed my collection to let's say `DataGrid`, when the grid is editable and I change a value, the `PropertyChanged` event is triggered by the `Datagrid` control on my source collection.

So it seems definitely possible. What's more, I even created my own type of observable collection implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` interfaces myself and it still works. `DataGrid` changes the item, my item's `PropertyChanged` event is triggered on the collection.

I want to do the same in my new control. I have the changed item, I have the property name, I have the source observable collection, now I just want the collection to trigger it's `PropertyChanged` event.

How to do it? How built-in WPF controls like `DataGrid` do that?

What is the code? Let's say it's something like "check box combo box". A kind of `ComboBox` with checkable items. The `ComboBox`es are complicated beasts, a lot of XAML I don't love, so I invented super easy way around it. I just `Menu` instead. I made my own control that contains menu with it's main item acting as a label / button, and checkable subitems acting as checkboxes. It looks just fine, it even kind of works.

The item source for that thing is an (observable) collection of (string value, bool isChecked) tuples. They are super easy to manipulate with LINQ. This thingie is to be used as a filter for a `DataGrid` view. It's filled with all available record types, and then they will be able to be unchecked and filtered from the view. The advantage of this approach is absolutely no XAML, no styling, no stuff for graphic designers. It looks OK with default styles and feel absolutely natural and intuitive without any visual tweaking.

The thingie is (almost) done, however, I want my ViewModel to be notified properly when my collection of filtered items changes, so my view model could request appropriate filtering.

I'm missing something obvious here...

Relevant view model framgents:

```cs
ObservableCollection<(string value, bool isChecked)> Checks = new();
Checks.Add(("Item1", true));
Checks.Add(("Item2", true));
Checks.PropertyChanged += (s, e) {
    // item changed reaction
}
```

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<c:Checks ItemsSource="{Binding Checks}"/>
<!-- ... -->
```

And my control source:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Woof.Windows.Controls {
    
    public class Checks : UserControl {

        public object Empty {
            get => GetValue(EmptyProperty);
            set => SetValue(EmptyProperty, value);
        }

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource {
            get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty EmptyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(Empty),
                typeof(object),
                typeof(Checks),
                new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnEmptyPropertyChanged))
            );

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(ItemsSource),
                typeof(IEnumerable),
                typeof(Checks),
                new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged))
            );

        private static void OnEmptyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            // TODO
        }

        private static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            if (sender is Checks control)
                control.OnItemsSourceChanged((IEnumerable)e.OldValue, (IEnumerable)e.NewValue);
        }

        private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue) {
            if (oldValue is INotifyCollectionChanged oldCollection)
                oldCollection.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(OnCollectionChanged);
            if (newValue is INotifyCollectionChanged newCollection) {
                newCollection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(OnCollectionChanged);
                if (newValue.OfType<object>().Any()) {
                    foreach (var item in newValue) AddItem(item);
                    SetHeader();
                }
            }
        }

        void OnCollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            switch (e.Action) {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    if (e.NewItems is null) return;
                    foreach (var item in e.NewItems) AddItem(item);
                    SetHeader();
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    if (e.OldItems is null) return;
                    foreach (var item in e.OldItems) RemoveItem(item);
                    SetHeader();
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Replace action is not implemented by Checks control");
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Move action is not implemented by Checks control");
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    foreach (var menuItem in MenuContent.Items.OfType<MenuItem>()) menuItem.Checked -= Item_Checked;
                    MenuContent.Items.Clear();
                    if (e.NewItems is null) return;
                    foreach (var item in e.NewItems) AddItem(item);
                    SetHeader();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private (object value, bool isChecked) GetCheckItem(object item) {
            if (item is ValueTuple<string, bool> label) return (label.Item1, label.Item2);
            else if (item is ValueTuple<object, bool> boxed) return (boxed.Item1, boxed.Item2);
            else return (item, false);
        }

        private void AddItem(object item) {
            var checkItem = GetCheckItem(item);
            if (MenuContent.Items.OfType<MenuItem>().Any(i => i.Tag == checkItem.value)) return;
            var newItem = new MenuItem {
                Header = checkItem.value,
                IsCheckable = true,
                IsChecked = checkItem.isChecked,
                Tag = checkItem.value,
            };
            newItem.Checked += Item_Checked;
            newItem.Unchecked += Item_Unchecked;
            MenuContent.Items.Add(newItem);
        }

        private void RemoveItem(object item) {
            var checkItem = GetCheckItem(item);
            var menuItem = MenuContent.Items.OfType<MenuItem>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Tag == checkItem.value);
            if (menuItem is not null) {
                menuItem.Checked -= Item_Checked;
                menuItem.Unchecked -= Item_Unchecked;
                MenuContent.Items.Remove(menuItem);
            }
        }

        private void Item_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var sourceValue = (e.Source as MenuItem)!.Tag;
            var sourceItem = ItemsSource.OfType<object>().Select(i => GetCheckItem(i)).FirstOrDefault(i => i.value == sourceValue);
            sourceItem.isChecked = true;
            if (ItemsSource is INotifyPropertyChanged nItemSource) {
                // nItemSource.PropertyChanged.Invoke(sourceItem, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("isChecked"));
                // Nah, this won't work. There must be another way...
            }
        }

        private void Item_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var sourceValue = (e.Source as MenuItem)!.Tag;
            var sourceItem = ItemsSource.OfType<object>().Select(i => GetCheckItem(i)).FirstOrDefault(i => i.value == sourceValue);
            sourceItem.isChecked = false;
            if (ItemsSource is INotifyPropertyChanged nItemSource) {
                // HERE, I NEED TO NOTIFY THE SOURCE!
            }
        }

        private void SetHeader() {
            var labels = ItemsSource
                .OfType<object>()
                .Select(i => GetCheckItem(i))
                .Where(i => i.isChecked)
                .Select(i => i.value.ToString())
                .ToArray();
            var header = String.Join(", ", labels);
            MenuContent.Header = header;
        }

        public Checks() {
            Content = MenuContainer = new Menu();
            MenuContainer.Items.Add(MenuContent = new MenuItem());
        }

        private readonly Menu MenuContainer;
        private readonly MenuItem MenuContent;

    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have a nasty bug here and I know it. `Tuple`s are IMMUTABLE. So anyway I won't be able to synchronize the collections of tuples by modifying their properties.

Fix to this is simple: I will use objects instead, like `var x = new { Value = "Item1", IsChecked = true }`. These are mutable, so...

Anyway, the main problem remains. I found a workaround:

```cs
if (ItemsSource is INotifyPropertyChanged nItemSource) {
    var t = ItemsSource.GetType();
    var m = t.GetMethod("OnPropertyChanged", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    m.Invoke(ItemsSource, new object?[] { sourceItem, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("isChecked") });
}
```

...but it's an ugly hack. But then again - it works. It does exactly what it should and what controls like `DataGrid` do. I mean - it's the same effect. I still don't know if they use Reflection to call protected methods of the collections.

Comment: The interface defines another behavior - when property of _that_ object changes, _it_ can notify others (others can subscribe to PropertyChanged event). What you want to do (notify the object about some external change) is not related to `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: you have made it too much complicated & ugly.

Comment: @MakAhmed You're 100% right here, that's why I fixed it in current version of the package. Most of the complexity is moved to `ObservableList<T>` class, yet - comparing its source code with `ObservableCollection<T>` - its "light" and super simple. What's important - I tested my class on a big "enterprise class" app with like 10 excel-like views open simultaneously, each with live search - it's visibly faster than built in .NET classes. Last code change: 2AM last night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I found the solution. You will probably not like it, but if it's ugly, but it works, why not use it?

```cs
#region ItemsSource notifier

private void NotifySourceItemChanged(object item, string propertyName)
    => ItemsSourceOnPropertyChanged(item, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

private void ItemsSourceOnPropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    => ItemsSourceOnPropertyChangedMethod?.Invoke(ItemsSource, new object?[] { sender, e });

private MethodInfo? GetItemsSourceOnPropertyChanged() {
    if (ItemsSource is null) return null;
    foreach (var method in ItemsSource.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)) {
        var parameters = method.GetParameters();
        if (parameters.Length == 2 &&
            parameters[0].ParameterType == typeof(object) &&
            parameters[1].ParameterType == typeof(PropertyChangedEventArgs)) return method;
    }
    return null;
}

private MethodInfo? ItemsSourceOnPropertyChangedMethod;

#endregion
```

We assume that our control contains the `ItemsSource` property.
Also, when `ItemsSource` property is changed we must call `GetItemsSourceOnPropertyChanged()`. It's done once on the binding.

Then, it will work if the object bound to the `ItemSource` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. I think `ObservableCollection` does.

Then, the collection must also contain `OnPropertyChanged()` method accepting an `object` and `PropertyChangedEventArgs`.

Again, `ObservableCollection` does.

The method is non-public, but well. We can call it.
If the `ItemsSource` is null, or it doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or it doesn't have non public method triggering the `PropertyChanged` event - nothing will happen.

So - if we provide a compatible collection - it will work.

I just finished my control. It works. My view model observes it's item collection, if one is checked or unchecked, the collection is updated and the event is triggered, so my view model can do whatever it needs with it.

Goal achieved, because now I can forget about the view implementation. The view model provide checkable items, and when their state is changed - it can react to that with zero knowledge about the view.

Also the view knows nothing about the view model. It only knows the collection type (and the item type to be precise).

So the binding is as pure as it gets.

Yes, I know, I could probably just make another bindable property in my control to provide the changes done in the view to the view model binding. It could be done without any hacks and easier. But I'm not sure. The consuming code would not be smaller, more readable or simpler. Nah, this is neat.

BTW, don't copy the code from the question, the full working version is on GitHub: https://github.com/HTD/Woof.Windows/blob/master/Woof.Windows.Controls/Checks.cs

Answer (score 0):

Firing the `PropertyChanged`-event has primarily nothing to do with WPF specifically per se, it just happens to coincide.

A `PropertyChanged`-event needs to be implemented in the class containing the property that should notify its changes. For example you have a simple class with a name:

```
class Test {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you want this class to raise an event whenever the Name changes, you have to implement it by hand like this:

```
class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string _name;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name {
        get => _name;
        set {
            if(value == _name) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now every time you change the `Name`-property, the `PropertyChanged`-event will fire. The same also goes for `ObservableCollection`s and the `CollectionChanged`-event, they are all manually implemented in the class itself.

WPF comes into play when you use Bindings. If you have a binding to a property configured in `TwoWay`- or `OneWayToSource`-mode, WPF will write the value back to the property when the value in the control changes. And because the property will fire the event whenever it changes, the event will fire whenever WPF decides to update the binding source.

**Regarding some of your statements:**

In your second paragraph you mix some things up, I think. Yes, an `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but this event is *for this class only* and not for its children. In general, the `PropertyChanged`-event only fires for the object with the property that has changed, it does not propagate. And the interface does indeed only define the event, as the trigger function is generally to be kept `private` or `protected`. If you want a collection, that is aware of changes to its children, you'll have to implement that yourself. WPF can do it automagically because while a DataGrid binds to a collection, the individual rows bind to the individual items of that collection (and to their events).

That also explains your third paragraph (in conjunction to how the event is generally implemented), because a change in the DataGrid will set the property and the property will in turn fire the event.

In your first snippet; you might want to register your event-handler to the `CollectionChanged`-event, not the `PropertyChanged`-event (if you want to listen to new items), as only the former will notify you if you add or remove items. And you'll need to register the event handler *before* you add your items, not after. Because if you do the event for Item1 and Item2 will already have been fired without a handler to listen to them, because you're too late. You will catch Items added afterwards though.

If you want to catch changes in the items themselves, `ObservableCollection`s `PropertyChanged` does not do that. You'll have to iterate over the items and attach an event listener to the individual items and also watch for collection changes. (As far as I can see in the [reference source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs), it only fires for the properties `Count` and the indexer `Item[]`)

Comment: I understand how INotifyPropertyChanged interface works. What I don't understand is how `DataGrid` makes my bound collection (that is `ObservableCollection`) fire its `PropertyChanged` event. It's magic, and it shouldn't be. I want just to replicate the exact `DataGrid` behavior. I know there are workarounds, like making my `OnPropertyChanged` in the collection public and calling it, but `DataGrid` does it differently. I have my source collection changed, I just don't get notification.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged seems to be one way - view model collection notifies the view. But somehow .NET is able also notify the view model back that it changed the collection internally. It's completely uncomprehensible to me how it gets done. Triggering the event can be done only in my view model. It is NOT done there. The view (`DataGrid`) does it. It looks like pure magic and trickery.

Comment: I called my protected `OnPropertyChanged` in my view model class via `Reflection`. Now it does EXACTLY what `DataGrid` does. The behavior is identical. My question is - does `DataGrid` uses reflection and that kind of ugly hack to achieve that effect?

Comment: So when using a DataGrid, the `PropertyChanged` on the *Collection* fires when you change an *Item* (ie edit a cell)? If it does, this sounds indeed strange and is not the expected behaviour at all.. I'll try to look into that, that sounds suspicous..

Comment: @Harry Ok, I did a minimal sample trying to reproduce your behavior... but it does work as expected (i.e. it fires nothing on the collection when editing the cells but fires on the individual items). What did you do to get that to work with a DataGrid at all??

Comment: https://github.com/HTD/Woof.Windows - see the demo.